# YouTube Player API Failing to Auto-Start (using Canonical Example)

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Browser: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 68.0.3440.42 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

OS: MacOS 10.13.5

Running the official example from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference observing a unusual bug.

note: Observed problem is a separate project, but replicated it with this canonical example.

Loading code from a local webserver running on port 8082:

`npx http-server`

note: Added console logs to the `onPlayerStateChange` function to assist in troubleshooting.

If run with dev tools NOT OPEN observe the bug.  If run with dev tools OPEN do not observe the bug.  Also, the bug does not appear to happen in latest version of Firefox.

Console Output with dev tools NOT open (until after) - BUG

[image: Console Output with dev tools NOT open (until after) - BUG]

Console Output with dev tools open - NO BUG

[image: Console Output with dev tools open - NO BUG]

Comment: The Google docs suggest that they monitor the `youtube-iframe-api` tag; was really hoping that given all their resources and that this appears to be fundamentally broken (and easy to recreate) someone would have picked on this within 24 hours. Any feedback (including I am crazy) would be greatly welcome.

Comment: Confirmed older Chrome version works fine:

"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

Newer Chrome version does not:

 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Believe the odd behavior with it working with Chrome Dev Tools open fooled me.  Just happened to find a reference to a new Chrome Browser flag (and feature) that disables autoplay videos.  The answer is to set the following flag on your browser:

chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy

Apparently, if you set the player with `playerVars` to be muted and it will also work too (verified myself).